# How to generate documentation for other projects within solution using DocFx

Tags: documentation-generation, docfx

I am using [DocFx](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx) to automatically generate documentation in Visual Studio 2015.

Per the [Getting Started](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx_getting_started.html) instructions, I added an empty ASP.NET 4 Web Application and used the Nuget Console to install the DocFx build package (e.g. `Install-Package docfx.msbuild`).  I built the site and it it generated documentation for code within the project.

I was wondering how to configure *docfx.json* to get DocFx to document code in other projects within the solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In *docfx.json*, there is an array of `metadata`.  The example `metadata` has a `src` object with `files` and `exclude` properties.

To point to another project in your solution, add a `cwd` property to `metadata` and change folders (i.e. "../Another.Project").

```json
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [ "**/*.csproj" ],
          "exclude": [ "**/bin/**", "**/obj/**", "_site/**" ],
          "cwd": "../Another.Project"
        }
      ],
      "dest": "obj/api"
    }
  ],
  "build": ...
}
```

Comment: I just referenced my solution file, and it found all the projets included. easy

Comment: It's worth noting that the `cwd` property has been deprecated since this was written, and should now be replaced with `src`. (Yes, `src: [ { src: "../" } ]`; it's a bit confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

**directory structure**

```
+---ClassLibrary
|   \---ClassLibrary.csproj
\---DocFxProject
    \---docfx.json
```

**docfx.json contents**
`cwd` and `src` are synonyms for the same property

```
{
  "metadata":
  [ 
    {
      "src":
      [
        {
          "files": [ "**/ClassLibrary.csproj" ],
          "src": "..",
          "exclude": [ "**/obj/**", "**/bin/**" ]
        } 
      ],
      "dest": "obj/api"
    }
  ],
  "build": { ... }
}
```